# Inverse Trig Derivative

Tags: calculus

Here's a simple problem that I'm not getting.

y = arcsec (1/x), where o < x < 1.

What is the derivative?

y' = 1 / { x^-1 * (x^(-2) - 1)^(1/2) } * -x^-2

y' = -x / { x^2 * (x^(-2) - 1)^(1/2) }

y' = -1 / { x * (x^(-2) - 1)^(1/2) }

That's what I'm getting.

But the answer should be y' = -1 / {1-x^2}^(1/2)
That's very different.

Comment: Would it simplify things to replace the function with $$y=\cos^{-1}(x)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
y =arcsec(\frac{1}{x})\Rightarrow \frac{1}{x}=\sec y=\frac{1}{\cos y}\Rightarrow x=\cos y.
$$
i.e

$$
x(y)=\cos y\Rightarrow x'(y)=-\sin y
$$

$$
x'(y)=\frac{1}{y'(x)}\Rightarrow y'(x)=\frac{1}{x'(y)}
$$
$$
y'(x)=-\frac{1}{\sin y}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\cos^2 y}}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
$$
$$
y' =arcsec(\frac{1}{x})=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
$$

Comment: Without re-expressing it with cos, how do you solve it? What did I do wrong?

Comment: if the above solution is then yours is all right, I tell you another way of solving

Comment: Oh, I see it is the same answer. Thank you!